# How to use the test operation of patch to update the ldap attribute value using scim

Tags: api, ldap, patch, scim

URL: http://localhost:8089/scim2/o=companydirectory/v2/Users/uid=bjensen@example.com,o=companydirectory
Method: Patch

```
 { 
           "schemas":[ 
              "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
           ],
           "Operations":[ 
              { 
                 "op":"test",
                 "value":{ 
                    "name":{ 
                       "givenName":"Daphne"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
```

Using the above example I should able to patch only if the current givenName value is not Daphne to Daphne as the new givenName value.

However, I get "status": "400" and "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
Please help.

Comment: Sorry, is there a question? Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I get "status": "400" and "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"